# Webviews on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, appstore-approval

The company, that I work for, wants to develop mobile apps using react native. The idea is to reuse the content on the websites instead of creating native views.

The current decision is to implement the apps like follows:

1. Create a react native app with bottom navigation and webviews as the
   content.
2. Each time the user clicks on a different section of the
   navigation, the webview loads a different page of the website into the web
   view.

For example the login functionality will be the login page from the website in a webview.

Is this sort of apps allowed to be published in the appStore? My thinking is that the app will not be allowed because the content of the pages can be changed!

Comment: This question is offtopic, not related to SW or programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not allowed to wrap a web app in a WebView and release it apple app store (btw: Google Play may reject your app too eventually).

you can make this if the web app is a small part of your whole app (for example: some food delivery apps use a WebView for chat with support, which is totally acceptable)

> **4.2 Minimum Functionality**
>
> Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond **a repackaged website**. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or **“app-like,”** it doesn’t belong on the App Store. If your App doesn’t provide some sort of lasting entertainment value or adequate utility, it may not be accepted. Apps that are simply a song or movie should be submitted to the iTunes Store. Apps that are simply a book or game guide should be submitted to the Apple Books Store.

you may get this rejection letter:

[image: screen]

Answer (score 1):

If you develop such an app you will get the following feedback from apple:

> We found that the experience your app provides is not sufficiently different from a web browsing experience, as it would be by incorporating native iOS functionality.
> While your app content may differ from your web site or other existing sites, the experience it provides does not differ significantly from the general experience of using Safari, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.
> You may wish to provide convenient access to a web property for a select or niche group of users - and may enhance that experience with features such as Push Notifications. However, such apps do not include enough native iOS functionality to be appropriate for the App Store. As an alternative, you may wish to provide instructions to your users on how to create a Safari web clip to add to their iOS device Home Screen. Or, if you would like to share the app with a select group of users, we recommend the Ad Hoc distribution method. See the iOS Provisioning Portal for details on Ad Hoc Distribution.
> We encourage you to review your app concept and evaluate whether you can incorporate additional features to enhance the user experience.

As apple guidelines says that:

**4.2 Minimum Functionality**

> Your app should include features, content, and UI **that elevate it beyond a repackaged website**. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store. If your App doesn't provide some sort of lasting entertainment value, or is just plain creepy, it may not be accepted. Apps that are simply a song or movie should be submitted to the iTunes Store. Apps that are simply a book or game guide should be submitted to the iBooks Store.